# Grails security check

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I am using **spring-security-core** and I have got more than ten controllers, I want to check whether user is logged in all the actions, I know one method of doing  `if(springSecurityService.isLoggedIn())` in all the actions, Is there any other way to do it, Instead of writing the same logic in all the actions/controllers

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to deny access to the actions entirely, there are a few ways of doing it.

You can put the `@grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured` annotation on the controller class, or action method.  You can also specify what needs authentication by URL by creating a request map.  You can either create a Requestmap domain object, or you can create a static request map in your `Config.groovy` with the `grails.plugins.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules` map.

There are more details in the [Spring Security Core manual](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/5%20Configuring%20Request%20Mappings%20to%20Secure%20URLs.html).

Answer (score 1):

If it were me I would take [ataylors](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190201/ataylor) answer one step further.  Do as he said, but instead of copying and pasting the same code in all of your controllers just put it in the `Controller.groovy` template once then run the `generate-all` command.  Templates are very powerful for things like this, and if you keep your templates up to date you can easily change 10 controllers, or 100 controllers as needed if/when your application evolves.

How to install templates:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html